# Why is the timer not working in windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I know this is an already asked question, but I couldn't find any solution. Here is my service.

```
class Program : ServiceBase
{
    private  Timer _timer;
    public Program()
    {
        ServiceName = "PrintTime";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run(new Program());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        _timer = new Timer(5000);
        _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteTimeToFile();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    private void WriteTimeToFile()
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\mylog.txt", FileMode.Append,            FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fs);
            streamWriter.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
            streamWriter.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I want to write `currentTime` into my `Mylog.txt` file every 5 seconds, but nothing happens after even 2 minutes. If I put the `WriteTimeToFile()` function into `OnStart` method it works fine, but not in a timer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Debug your service by attaching the process from visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after several hours, I noticed that the timer works fine. There was nothing wrong with timer. But the problem is about `FileStream` constructor. `FileMode.Append` only works by `FileAccess.Write`.

So fixing this line of code solved the problem .

Anyway, thanks for your attention.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"d:\mylog.txt", 
                       FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
```

Answer (score 7):

What is the timer's namespace? It needs to be `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`.

See here: [Best Timer for using in a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246697/windows-service-and-timer)

Comment: `Elapsed` indicates Timers.Timer

Comment: It is System.Timer.Timer . But I have  tried System.Threading.Timer too . same result .

Comment: I had a windows forms timer as I inserted it using the toolbox. The one time I use toolbox... Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The Service must be running under a Windows account with permissions to write to the D:\ directory.

Check the exceptions in Event Viewer to see if there is an unauthorized access exception.

Also put a break point in the _timer_Elapsed method to verify that it gets called and step through the code.

Comment: If writing to d:\directory is denied , so why putting the WriteTimeToFile() into onStart method works ?

Answer (score 0):

[Windows service with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885013/windows-service-with-timer-c-net/12886071#12886071)

Read my answer in this post...

Maybe you miss 
    timer.AutoReset = true;